# Best way to threading when with/as is needed (python, pyqt)

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

I'm trying to run a worker class using a qthread. I can do this without a problem if the worker is instantiated with workerObject = workerClass(). How can I do this if the worker class needs to execute always the **exit**?

Below is a sample code that tries to do that. Unfortunately, by running this, the **exit** function doesn't get executed and most probably this is because the thread is not aware about the with/as statement

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import sys
import time

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(400, 284)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 361, 191))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 250, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Print", None))



class UI_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UI_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run)


    def run(self):
        self.t = QThread()
        self.x = None
        with worker() as self.x:        
            self.x.signal.connect(self.write)
            self.x.moveToThread(t) 
            t.started.connect(self.x.run)
            t.start()

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def write(self, text):
        self.textEdit.append("Running")
        qtObject.processEvents()




class worker(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(worker, self).__init__(parent)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def run(self):
        self.signal.emit("Running")
        time.wait(5)
        raise Exception

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_type:
            self.signal.emit("Exception")




def main(qtObject, guiObj):
    guiObj.show()
    qtObject.exec_()
    qtObject.processEvents()


qtObject = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
guiObj = UI_MainWindow()
main(qtObject, guiObj)
```

LE: The context involves the need to print in a QTextEdit window any failure message coming from the worker class. Any exception raised during the worker class execution is handled in its exit function so that whatever wrong happens, the script to end gracefully providing the user with meaningful information and instructions.

Comment: I wonder, is there some kind of pipelining mechanism to force the __init__(), __enter__(), run() and __exit__(), simulating the with/as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from user3419537 solution, I've come in the end with the following solution. A second signal (statusSignal) is used to carry back to the main class all the exception related information so that the exit function can be called.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import sys
import time

class err(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = [a for a in args]

mainThread = QtCore.QThread.currentThread()

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(400, 284)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 361, 191))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 250, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Print", None))



class UI_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UI_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run)

    def run(self):
        self.t = QThread()
        self.x = worker()          
        self.x.signal.connect(self.write)
        self.x.statusSignal.connect(self.runExit)
        self.x.moveToThread(self.t) 
        self.t.started.connect(self.x.run)
        self.t.start()

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def write(self, text):
        self.textEdit.append(text)
        qtObject.processEvents()

    @pyqtSlot(object, object, object)
    def runExit(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.t2 = QThread()
        self.x.moveToThread(self.t2)
        self.t2.started.connect(lambda: self.x.__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))
        self.t2.start()






class worker(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    statusSignal = pyqtSignal(object, object, object)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(worker, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.signal.emit("Run")
            time.sleep(2)
            self.moveToThread(mainThread)
            raise err("err message")
        except err:
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            self.statusSignal.emit(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_type:
            self.signal.emit(exc_value.args[0])



def main(qtObject, guiObj):
    guiObj.show()
    qtObject.exec_()
    qtObject.processEvents()


qtObject = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
guiObj = UI_MainWindow()
main(qtObject, guiObj)
```

Most probably there are still some tweaks to be made to the code, but as it stands at the moment, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The `__exit__` function ***does*** get executed, the issue is that due to the non-blocking nature of threads, the `with` construct immediately terminates (calling `worker.__exit__`) before the worker "completes" and raises the exception.

One way to achieve what you want is to surround the code in `worker.run()` with a `try/except` statement to catch any unhandled exceptions and perform any cleanup or emitting of signals.

```
def run(self):
    try:
        self.signal.emit("Running")
        time.sleep(5)
        raise Exception
    except:
        self.signal.emit("Exception")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The solution replaces the exit actions with the ones from except and it does the job. Still, I was wondering if there is any way to really force the execution of exit. Meanwhile I've started playing with another signal that gets set with the error message and whenever this happens, UI_MainWindow to call the exit function of the worker. It might be nonsense, but I really need that exit to get executed. One thing that I need to figure out is how to set the exc_type, exc_value and traceback. These guys must be set in the error message of the second signal, I guess.

Comment: As I explained, `__exit__` *is* being executed. You can verify this by inserting a `print` statement at the beginning. However, it's not being called when you expect it to and the exception signal does not get emitted. What are you trying to do from the `__exit__` function that you can't do in an exception handler?